# How to resolve ` ⨯ FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call initializeApp() first (app/no-app).`

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js

In my NextJs app, I am trying to allow user to update profile image as well as brand logo. I decided to use `Firebase Storage` to achieve this, but after setting up the configuration, and running the app to test I got this error:

```
 ⨯ FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call initializeApp() first (app/no-app).
    at getApp (file:///Users/admin/path-to/frontend/node_modules/@firebase/app/dist/esm/index.esm2017.js:479:29)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(api)/./firebase.js:27:65) {
  code: 'app/no-app',
  customData: { appName: '[DEFAULT]' }
}
```

Below are the code files responsible for this:

```
// `../../firebase.js` (root folder)
import { getApp, initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getStorage, ref, uploadBytes } from "firebase/storage";

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    databaseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
    projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
    measurementId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = getApp().length ? getApp() : initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const storage = getStorage(app);

// Create a child reference for profile storage
const profilesRef = ref(storage, 'profile');

// Create a child reference for images storage
const imagesRef = ref(storage, 'images/brand');

// Create file metadata including the content type
const metadata = {
    contentType: 'image/jpeg',
};

// Sample usage of uploadBytes
const file = new Blob(['Hello, world!'], { type: 'text/plain' });

// Update storage reference based on the type of image being uploaded
let storageRef;

if (fileToUpdate === 'profileImage') {
    storageRef = ref(profilesRef);
} else if (fileToUpdate === 'brandLogo') {
    storageRef = ref(imagesRef, 'brand');
}

const uploadTask = uploadBytes(storageRef, file, metadata);

export { storage, profilesRef, imagesRef, uploadTask };
```

```
// `/profile.js

import { Fragment, useState, createContext } from 'react';
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";


const UserContext = createContext();

export default function ProfilePg() {
    const [sidebarOpen, setSidebarOpen] = useState(false);
    const { data: session, status } = useSession();
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
        profileImage: null,
        brandName: '',
        brandLogo: null
    });
    const [passwordData, setPasswordData] = useState({
        newPassword: '',
        confirmPassword: '',
    });
    const [imageTag, setImageTag] = useState({ brandLogo: null, profileImage: null });

    const handlePasswordChange = (e) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        setPasswordData((prevData) => ({
            ...prevData,
            [name]: value,
        }));
    };

    const handlePasswordSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const baseUrl = '/api/changepassword';

        try {
            const response = await fetch(baseUrl, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(passwordData),
            });

            if (response.ok) {
                // Optionally, you can handle success here
                console.log('Password changed successfully');
            } else {
                // Handle errors
                console.error('Error changing password');
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error changing password', error);
        }
    };

    const { user } = session || {};

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        setFormData((prevData) => ({
            ...prevData,
            [name]: value,
        }));
    };

    const handleFileChange = (e, fieldName) => {
        const file = e.target.files[0];
        const reader = new FileReader();

        setFormData((prevData) => ({
            ...prevData,
            [fieldName]: file,
        }));

        reader.onload = (readerEvent) => {
            setImageTag((prevTags) => ({
                ...prevTags,
                [fieldName]: readerEvent.target.result,
            }));
        };

        if (file) {
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
    };

    const removeImage = () => {
        setImageTag(null)
    }

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const baseUrl = '/api/profileupdate';

        try {
            const formDataObject = new FormData();

            // Append user email
            formDataObject.append('data[email]', user.email);

            // Append regular form data
            Object.entries(formData).forEach(([key, value]) => {
                formDataObject.append(`data[${key}]`, value);
            });

            // Append file data
            if (formData.profileImage instanceof File) {
                formDataObject.append('profileImage', formData.profileImage);
            }

            // Append file data
            if (formData.brandLogo instanceof File) {
                formDataObject.append('brandLogo', formData.brandLogo);
            }

            const response = await fetch(baseUrl, {
                method: 'POST',
                body: formDataObject,
            });

            if (response.ok) {
                // Optionally, you can handle success here
                console.log('Profile updated successfully');
            } else {
                // Handle errors
                console.error('Error updating profile');
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error updating profile', error);
        }
    };
    return (
        <div>
        <form className="md:col-span-2" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                                    <div className="grid grid-cols-1 gap-x-6 gap-y-8 sm:max-w-xl sm:grid-cols-6">
                                        <div className="col-span-full flex flex-col gap-x-8">
                                            {imageTag.profileImage
                                                ? <img id="profileImageTag" className="h-28 w-28 flex-none rounded-lg bg-white object-cover" src={imageTag.profileImage} alt="Profile Image" />
                                                : <img id="profileImageTag" className="h-28 w-28 flex-none rounded-lg bg-white object-cover" src={user?.image} alt="Profile Image" />
                                            }
                                            <span className='mt-1'><input type="file" className='w-full h-10' accept="image/*" onChange={(e) => handleFileChange(e, 'profileImage')} /></span>
                                            <span className='text-xs'>Edit image</span>
                                            <div>
                                                <p className="mt-2 text-xs leading-5 text-slate-400">JPG, GIF or PNG. 1MB max.</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div className="sm:col-span-3">
                                            <label htmlFor="firstName" className="block text-sm font-medium leading-6 text-black">
                                                First name
                                            </label>
                                            <div className="mt-2">
                                                <input
                                                    type="text"
                                                    name="firstName"
                                                    value={formData.firstName}
                                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                                    id="firstName"
                                                    placeholder='Updated your first name'
                                                    autoComplete="first-name"
                                                    className="block w-full rounded-md border bg-white/5 py-1.5 text-black shadow-sm ring-1 ring-inset ring-white/10 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-indigo-500 sm:text-sm sm:leading-6"
                                                />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div className="sm:col-span-3">
                                            <label htmlFor="lastName" className="block text-sm font-medium leading-6 text-black">
                                                Last name
                                            </label>
                                            <div className="mt-2">
                                                <input
                                                    type="text"
                                                    name="lastName"
                                                    id="lastName"
                                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                                    value={formData.lastName}
                                                    placeholder='Updated your last name'
                                                    autoComplete="last-name"
                                                    className="block w-full rounded-md border bg-white/5 py-1.5 text-black shadow-sm ring-1 ring-inset ring-white/10 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-indigo-500 sm:text-sm sm:leading-6"
                                                />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div className="col-span-full">
                                            <label htmlFor="email" className="block text-sm font-medium leading-6 text-black">
                                                Email address
                                            </label>
                                            <span className='text-slate-500'>current email: {user?.email}</span>
                                        </div>

                                        <div id="brandCompany" className="col-span-full">
                                            <label htmlFor="username" className="block text-sm font-medium leading-6 text-black">
                                                Brand | Company
                                            </label>
                                            <div className="mt-2">
                                                <div className="flex rounded-md bg-white/5 ring-1 ring-inset ring-white/10 focus-within:ring-2 focus-within:ring-inset focus-within:ring-indigo-500">
                                                    <input
                                                        type="text"
                                                        name="brandName"
                                                        id="brandName"
                                                        onChange={handleChange}
                                                        value={formData.brandName}
                                                        autoComplete="brandName"
                                                        className="flex-1 rounded-md border bg-transparent py-1.5 pl-1 text-black focus:ring-0 sm:text-sm sm:leading-6"
                                                        placeholder="Update your Brand name"
                                                    />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="col-span-full mt-3 flex items-center gap-x-8">

                                                <div>
                                                    {imageTag.brandLogo
                                                        ? <img id="brandLogoImageTag" className="h-28 w-28 flex-none rounded-lg bg-white object-cover" src={imageTag.brandLogo} alt="Brand Logo" />
                                                        : <img id="brandLogoImageTag" className="h-28 w-28 flex-none rounded-lg bg-white object-cover" src={user?.image} alt="Brand Logo" />
                                                    }
                                                    <span className='flex mt-2 flex-col text-sm'><input className='w-full h-10' type="file" accept="image/*" onChange={(e) => handleFileChange(e, 'brandLogo')} />112px by 112px</span>
                                                    <span className='text-xs'>Edit image</span>
                                                    <div>
                                                        <p className="mt-2 text-xs leading-5 text-slate-400">JPG, GIF or PNG. 1MB max.</p>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div className="mt-8 flex">
                                        <div className="mt-4 flex w-44">
                                            <button type="submit" className="text-red-700 hover:text-white border border-red-700 hover:bg-red-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-red-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 text-center me-2 mb-2 dark:border-red-500 dark:text-red-500 dark:hover:text-white dark:hover:bg-red-600 dark:focus:ring-red-900">
                                                Update Profile
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                              </div>
                 </form>
        </div>
    
    )
}
```

and lastly,

```
// `/api/update-profile.js`

import multer from 'multer';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';
import { getServerSession } from 'next-auth/next';
import { authOptions } from './auth/[...nextauth]';
import { app, storage, profilesRef, imagesRef } from '../../firebase';

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

// Configure multer storage
const upload = multer({ storage: multer.memoryStorage() });

export default async function handler(req, res) {
    const session = await getServerSession(req, res, authOptions);

    // Use different child references for profile images and brand logos
    const profileStorageRef = ref(storage, 'profile');
    const brandLogoStorageRef = ref(storage, 'images/brand');

    // Perform the upload operations as needed
    upload.fields([{ name: 'profileImage' }, { name: 'brandLogo' }])(req, res, async (err) => {
        try {
            if (err) {
                console.error('Error uploading files', err);
                return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error uploading files' });
            }

            // Change this line
            const data = req.body;

            const { email, firstName, lastName, brandName } = data;
            const lowercaseEmail = email.toLowerCase();

            if (!email || !firstName || !lastName || !brandName) {
                return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Required data is missing' });
            }

            const profileImageData = req.files['profileImage'] ? req.files['profileImage'][0].buffer : null;
            const brandLogoData = req.files['brandLogo'] ? req.files['brandLogo'][0].buffer : null;

            try {
                if (profileImageData) {
                    // Handle profileImage file upload
                    const profileImageMetadata = { contentType: 'image/jpeg' };
                    const profileImageFilename = `${uuidv4()}_profileImage.jpg`;
                    const storageRefProfileImage = ref(profileStorageRef, profileImageFilename);

                    await uploadBytes(storageRefProfileImage, profileImageData, profileImageMetadata);
                }

                if (brandLogoData) {
                    // Handle brandLogo file upload
                    const brandLogoMetadata = { contentType: 'image/jpeg' };
                    const brandLogoFilename = `${uuidv4()}_brandLogo.jpg`;
                    const storageRefBrandLogo = ref(brandLogoStorageRef, brandLogoFilename);

                    await uploadBytes(storageRefBrandLogo, brandLogoData, brandLogoMetadata);
                }

                // Update the user information in the database
                const updatedUser = await prisma.user.update({
                    where: {
                        email: lowercaseEmail,
                    },
                    data: {
                        firstName,
                        lastName,
                        brandName,
                        profileImage: profileImageData ? `profile/${uuidv4()}_profileImage.jpg` : null,
                        brandLogo: brandLogoData ? `images/brand/${uuidv4()}_brandLogo.jpg` : null,
                    },
                });

                // console.log('User updated:', updatedUser);
                console.log('User updated:', updatedUser);

                // Respond with success
                return res.status(200).json({ message: 'Profile updated successfully' });
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error processing request:', error);
                return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error processing request' });
            } finally {
                // Disconnect Prisma after handling the request
                await prisma.$disconnect();
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error:', error);
            return res.status(500).json({ message: 'There is an error' });
        }
    });
}
```

Any pointers to resolving this is very much appreciated. Thanks